# Setup Derelict3 with GLFW

Tags: d, glfw

I'm trying to use `OpenGL` and `GLFW` with `Derelict3` for the D language, but I have some problems with the `glfw3.dll` and I'm not sure about what I did wrong:

- I downloaded `Derelict3` from https://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3 and run the `build.d` and linked the `*.lib` (DMD compiler) with my project.
- As `Derelict3` seems to need the `glfw3.dll` I cloned the Git repository `git://glfw.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/glfw/glfw`.
- I created a folder `build` and called `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..` from within and got a `glfw.dll`, `glfwdll.lib` and `libglfw.a`.
- Then I copied the `glfw.dll` into my project directory and renamed it to `glfw3.dll`.

But when I run my program I get the error:

```
derelict.util.exception.SymbolLoadException@..\import\derelict\util\exception.d(38): Failed to load symbol glfwSetErrorCallback from shared library glfw3.dll
```

Does anybody know how to setup the `Derelict3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong Repo, `glfw3` moved to github: https://github.com/elmindreda/glfw.

The error you see is caused, by the old version of `glfw`, in this old version is no symbol called `glfwSetErrorCallback`.